# TideSDK and XAMPP bundle package conflict

Tags: windows, xampp, bundle, conflict, tidesdk

First of all, I'm swiss, so forgive me if I mistake; My english is not so rich.

Having XAMPP installed on w7, when I try to launch the application (bundle package created by TideSDK Developer) I get several error notices because TideSDK goes searching for libraries and so in the XAMPP path.

Otherwise, if I rename the XAMPP folder like this: `C:/windows/ZZZxampp/` everything works.

So I was wondering how could it be possible to **tell the application to NOT searching in XAMPP path**

Regards and thank you.

---

Details:

I get error messages even from a new empty project launched from TideSDK Developer. I think then maybe the problem is a non-well-done downgrade of xampp.
Now it is v1.7.3, but in xampp/htdocs/xampp/.version file I can still see v1.8.1.

I think it makes sanse because many errors are refered to php; with this message:

```
...unable to...
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6<-------
PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC8<----------
These options need to match
```

But I'm not an expert, so maybe I'm wrong. So, here some code.

manifest:

```
#appname: Test
#appid: dfgsdgnjfdxcydghssdf
#guid: a9d7f8a0-8389-4dd7-a7d6-293a9b04787e
#version: 1.0
#image: default_app_logo.png
#publisher: G
#url: www.test.com
runtime: 1.3.1-beta
app: 1.3.1-beta
codec: 1.3.1-beta
database: 1.3.1-beta
filesystem: 1.3.1-beta
media: 1.3.1-beta
monkey: 1.3.1-beta
network: 1.3.1-beta
platform: 1.3.1-beta
process: 1.3.1-beta
ui: 1.3.1-beta
worker: 1.3.1-beta
php: 1.3.1-beta
```

tiapp.xml

```
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">

<id>dfgsdgnjfdxcydghssdf</id>
<name>Test</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<publisher>G</publisher>
<url>www.test.com</url>
<icon>default_app_logo.png</icon>
<copyright>2012 by G</copyright>

<window>
<id>initial</id>
<title>Test</title>
<url>app://index.html</url>
<width>700</width>
<max-width>3000</max-width>
<min-width>0</min-width>
<height>500</height>
<max-height>3000</max-height>
<min-height>0</min-height>
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<resizable>true</resizable>
<chrome scrollbars="true">true</chrome>
<maximizable>true</maximizable>
<minimizable>true</minimizable>
<closeable>true</closeable>
</window>
</ti:app>
```

Index.html is only html...

And the log of packaging

```
Preparing to package desktop app together with runtime. One moment...
Staging Test
-> Copying contents from C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> Copying installer from C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\installer to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> Copying runtime to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\app\1.3.1-beta\\tideapp.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\app\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\app\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\codec\1.3.1-beta\\tidecodec.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\codec\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\codec\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\database\1.3.1-beta\\tidedatabase.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\database\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\database\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\filesystem\1.3.1-beta\\tidefilesystem.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\filesystem\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\filesystem\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\media\1.3.1-beta\\tidemedia.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\media\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\media\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\monkey\1.3.1-beta\\tidemonkey.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\monkey\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\monkey\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\network\1.3.1-beta\\tidenetwork.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\network\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\network\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\platform\1.3.1-beta\\tideplatform.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\platform\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\platform\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\process\1.3.1-beta\\tideprocess.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\process\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\process\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\ui\1.3.1-beta\\default.css does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\ui\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\ui\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\worker\1.3.1-beta\\tideworker.dll does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\worker\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\worker\1.3.1-beta
-> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\php\1.3.1-beta\\install.txt does not exist
-> Copying C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\php\1.3.1-beta ==> C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\php\1.3.1-beta
-> Copying tiboot.exe to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-8 2012-12-05 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
-> Launching: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\ReplaceVistaIcon.exe "C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\Test.exe" "C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\Resources\_converted_icon.ico"
->
Language="1033" Codepage="1252"
UpgradeCode="a9d7f8a0-8389-4dd7-a7d6-293a9b04787e">
Description="Test"
Comments="None provided" Manufacturer="None provided"
InstallerVersion="300" Languages="1033" Compressed="yes" SummaryCodepage="1252" />
Minimum='0.0.1' IncludeMinimum='yes'
Maximum="1.0.0" IncludeMaximum='yes' />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
-> Ignoring error: [Error 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato: 'C:\\Users\\G\\Desktop\\Test\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs.wixobj'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\tidebuilder.py", line 147, in
app.package(options.destination, bundle=bundle)
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\win32_app.py", line 174, in package
wix_bin_dir = self.get_wix_bin_directory()
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\win32_app.py", line 197, in get_wix_bin_directory
raise Exception('Could not find WiX v3 bin directory')
Exception: Could not find WiX v3 bin directory
Done packaging!
```

Comment: Can you provide the paths where exactly you have installed xampp/tideSdk on your hdd?

Comment: XAMPP: C:/xampp/ (it was wrong before) - TideSDK: Developer C:/Program Files(x86)/TideSDK Developer/ - TideSDK: C:/ProgramData/TideSDK/

Comment: I have the same setup, but no problems. Can you share your sourcecode of the project, so I can check if the error is in there.

Comment: Added some details...can I ask you wich version of xampp you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

You're right: WIX needed to be fixed.

Replacing the string

```
'Windows Installer XML v3'
```

with

```
'WiX Toolset v3.7' //my version installed'
```

in

```
C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\win32_app.py
```

**has solved the packing issue.** (even with light.exe errors, it works)

here the new log:

```
Preparing to package desktop app together with runtime. One moment...
Staging Test
-> Copying contents from C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> Copying installer from C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\installer to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> Copying runtime to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\app\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\codec\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\database\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\filesystem\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\media\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\monkey\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\network\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\platform\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\process\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\ui\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\worker\1.3.1-beta
-> Already up to date: C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\modules\php\1.3.1-beta
-> Copying tiboot.exe to C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-8 2012-12-05 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
-> Launching: C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\ReplaceVistaIcon.exe "C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\Test.exe" "C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\Test\Resources\_converted_icon.ico"
->
Language="1033" Codepage="1252"
UpgradeCode="a9d7f8a0-8389-4dd7-a7d6-293a9b04787e">
Description="Test"
Comments="None provided" Manufacturer="None provided"
InstallerVersion="300" Languages="1033" Compressed="yes" SummaryCodepage="1252" />
Minimum='0.0.1' IncludeMinimum='yes'
Maximum="1.0.0" IncludeMaximum='yes' />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="ApplicationIcon.exe"
IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
NOT Installed
-> Launching: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WiX Toolset v3.7\\bin\\candle.exe', '-out', 'C:\\Users\\G\\Desktop\\Test\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs.wixobj', 'C:\\Users\\G\\Desktop\\Test\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs']
Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 3.7.1119.0
Copyright (C) Outercurve Foundation. All rights reserved.
installer.wxs
-> Launching: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WiX Toolset v3.7\\bin\\light.exe', '-ext', ' WixUIExtension', '-out', u'C:\\Users\\G\\Desktop\\Test\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\Test.msi', 'C:\\Users\\G\\Desktop\\Test\\packages\\win32\\bundle\\installer.wxs.wixobj']
Windows Installer Xml Linker version 3.7.1119.0
Copyright (C) Outercurve Foundation. All rights reserved.
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.100.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.101.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.103.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.104.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.193.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.238.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Component, Column: KeyPath, Key(s): downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.100.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.101.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.103.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.104.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.193.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.238.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3044.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3051.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.3069.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.1833.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4027.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4028.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4029.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4045.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_manifest.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4052.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: Registry, Column: Registry, Key(s): reg_downlevel_payload.8.0.50727.4053.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE25: Possible dependency failure as we do not find CRT.Policy.63E949F6_03BC_5C40_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E@0 v in ModuleSignature table
C:\Users\G\Desktop\Test\packages\win32\bundle\installer.wxs(15) : warning LGHT1076 : ICE61: This product should remove only older versions of itself. The Maximum version is not less than the current product. (1.0.0 1.0.0)
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table InstallUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdminExecuteSequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdminUISequence
light.exe : warning LGHT1076 : ICE82: This action SystemFolder.98CB24AD_52FB_DB5F_FF1F_C8B3B9A1E18E has duplicate sequence number 1 in the table AdvtExecuteSequence
Done packaging!
```

Anyway, the error messages that I was talking about are something like 20 **modal windows** fired consecutively when trying to launch/execute the app. 
When I rename the xampp folder **I can launch/debug, and execute the app from package...without any modal error.**

I've tryed to install a new version of xampp (1.8.1) and... nice, with a **clean** installation only one error:

```
PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module 
Module compiled with build ID=API 20100525
PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626
These options need to match
```

Why TideSDK hates XAMPP?

Really: couldn't it be that the application tries to use the default system resources first?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in no way related to your local XAMPP installation.
You did not run your application for testing/debuggin purposes, but tried to start a packaging process (which generates a executable file and/or installation package to distribute).

The packaging on your windows machine failed, because you did not install WIX toolset properly.

Comment: To launch your app in TideSDK Developer, you have to click the button "Launch App" in the "Test&Package" section. If you click the buttons "Package with Runtime" or "Package without" runtime, you start the packaging process which tries to generate a distributable package for you.

Comment: Wait wait wait! Rewind. :D More/new details added

Comment: Maybe if you watch this video you can understand better what I mean...[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awdfdXHnIkQ)